# Loop through a nested JSON object to find a value id

Tags: javascript, postman

```
    "results": {
    "data": {
        "facets": {
            "60749428": {
                "id": 60749428,
                "name": "KC Content Content Kind"
            },
            "60750276": {
                "id": 60750276,
                "name": "KC Content Product Version"
            },
            "69107204": {
                "id": 69107204,
                "name": "KC Video Audience"
            },
            "69127027": {
                "id": 69127027,
                "name": "KC Content Kind ID"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to loop through this nested json object by going into the facet object and say if the name attribute is "KC Content Kind ID" then return the id for that corresponding name attribute

So after getting my api call with postman I was trying to get the corresponding id of the "KC Content Kind ID" in my success function this way, but since its not an array I was wondering if each will work in jquery.

```
    //Get Available Kinds
function getAvailableKinds() {
    $.ajax({
        url: csexe + "/api/v2/facets/" +getLocationId(),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("OTCSticket", getAuthToken());
        },
        success: function(response) {
            var obj = response.results.data.facets;
            $.each(obj, function(item, value){
                 if ( value == 'KC Content Kind ID') {
                     var idRequired = obj.id;
                 }
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("An error occurred... Look at the console");
            $("body").html('<p>status code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>Error Thrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>Response Text:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Show us the code

Comment: Good day, so what I had done was after getting my postman result from my api call. This was my code in the "success" function.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the string over and then do a simple loop.

```
var jsonObj = (JSON.parse("your json here")).data.facets;

for (i = 0; i<jsonObj.length;i++)
{
    if(jsonObj[i].name == "KC Content Kind ID")
        return jsobObj[i].id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be by using `Object.values`  function in conjunction with `Array.prototype.filter`. You can then take the first item from the array returned by the `filter` method (since each ID should be unique) and display it's ID.

```js
const o = { "results": { "data": { "facets": { "60749428": { "id": 60749428, "name": "KC Content Content Kind" }, "60750276": { "id": 60750276, "name": "KC Content Product Version" }, "69107204": { "id": 69107204, "name": "KC Video Audience" }, "69127027": { "id": 69127027, "name": "KC Content Kind ID"}}}}};

const [a] = Object.values(o.results.data.facets).filter(f => f.name == "KC Content Kind ID");

console.log(a.id);
```

Comment: You could also use `Array.prototype.find` in place of `Array.prototype.filter` - but it wont work for all browsers (Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.keys` and `find`

```js
const obj = {"results": {"data": {"facets": {"60749428": {"id": 60749428,"name": "KC Content Content Kind"},"60750276": {"id": 60750276,"name": "KC Content Product Version"},"69107204": {"id": 69107204,"name": "KC Video Audience"},"69127027": {"id": 69127027,"name": "KC Content Kind ID"}}}}};
    
const facets = obj.results.data.facets;
const result = Object.keys(facets).find(v => facets[v].name === 'KC Content Kind ID');
//your object keys are equal to id, you can just return key
console.log(result);

// if your object keys can be different from id you can do this
console.log(facets[result].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "results": {
    "data": {
      "facets": {
        "60749428": {
          "id": 60749428,
          "name": "KC Content Content Kind"
        },
        "60750276": {
          "id": 60750276,
          "name": "KC Content Product Version"
        },
        "69107204": {
          "id": 69107204,
          "name": "KC Video Audience"
        },
        "69127027": {
          "id": 69127027,
          "name": "KC Content Kind ID"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
let facets = obj.results.data.facets;
let id; 
for(let key in facets){
  if(facets[key].name == 'KC Content Kind ID'){
    id = facets[key].id;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(id);
```